# simple captcha gem that is compatible with rails 4?

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, captcha

Could someone suggest a simple captcha gem that is compatible with rails 4?
I have tried several solutions but they all incompatible or cybersome.

I have used the

```
#gem "galetahub-simple_captcha", :require => "simple_captcha"
```

But that one is desperately outdated and I don't have time to convert it to rails 4.

- I have looked at the ruby toolbox entry for captcha. 
  Basically I only want the simple captcha ( no re-captcha ) to show up in certain pages just like the gale tub gem is doing.
- https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&o=desc&q=simple_captcha&ref=searchresults&s=updated&type=Repositories nothing much either. Any suggestions? Perhaps making that existing gem rails 4 compatible is not that hard to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned gem is updated and works with rails 4